# Unable to open for writing: File too large

Tags: php

I am getting this error. What does it mean?

> Warning: imagejpeg(): Unable to open
>   '/home/content/59/.../images/___htmlthumbnail_0b1292bbbcc4199eb4f50651962cf4641329752862.jpg'
>   for writing: File too large in
>   /home/content/59/.../cms/classes/resize.class.php on line 50

This is what happens.

1. Big image is uploaded
2. Big image - if too big - is resized to
   the correct dimensions.
3. 4 thumbnails are created.

Step 1 is working fine. The main image is being uploaded. The problem is coming with creating the thumbnails. The script is failing here.

```
imagejpeg($this->image,$filename,$compression);
```

This error is only happening on one server. We deploy our script to hundreds of servers a year. I just cannot find out what this error means. The file is uploading fine so I don't see why it is too large. If the server was running out of memory it would have a memory error surely.

The image I am uploading isn't even particularly big. Its 33KB. 780 x 120px.

Has anyone seen this error before? I assume something server side needs to be adjusted as the script works just fine every where else.

Comment: How many files are in the directory you're trying to write to?

Comment: Try: uploading a much smaller image, and uploading to a different directory. These would at least allow you to narrow down the cause of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

check php.ini settings... if you don't have the access contact the support i'm sure they will help you out...

Comment: What php.ini setting in particular?